# Modify google maps api

Tags: api, dictionary, url-rewriting

Is it possible to add more functions for google map by using Google map API?
For example, I would like to add more indicators including stairs, elevators and etc in Google Map, is it possible?

Besides, I would like to add one more function, let's say create a new route without stairs based on the Google Map API, will it work?

Comment: I'm sure you already can do this with the actual API.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean.

If you are using Google Maps in your own website/application you can add custom markers/overlay based on your own data.  (see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays).  You can add markers/overlays for pretty much anything you can think of.

If you mean add it to the usual maps.google.com site, then no you can't as far as I'm aware.

You can't change the API as Google control that, but you can use the API on your site however you like.